How could a human fire himself above a fence, then parachute downwards?
Illegal immigrants would seek ways to pass a border fence and digging under it or climbing on it isn't always possible so they might seek a way to hover over it.
Using an expensive jetpack costing millions of USDs or a big heavy powered paraglider isn't feasible in this case; something with an engine is needed indeed, but much smaller than these, something that someone could put in a bag or hold in one hand.
How could a human fire himself above a fence just a few meters, then parachute downwards?

Step 1. Do a web search to find the minimum altitude for a parachute descent. Then consider that in relation to your question.

@Transistor thanks. From a quick search I understand that the minimum is around 100 meters, well then maybe I should replace the word "parachute" in another but I don't know what.

What country are you trying to escape from?

Ditch the schute and join the circus. A certain level of acrobatics is likely required. Then again, if you are a skilled athlete, other countries might just let you in legally! Also, foreign projectiles may be met with projectiles.

Humbly, and gladly, I am not trying to escape from any country at the moment, but I do want to help some who are :) anyway as a question in mechanical engineering this is totally serious and I expect to get an answer most of us here could learn from.
